# How to authenticate Hashicorp Vault over TLS?

Tags: tls1.2, hashicorp-vault

I'm new to Hashicorp Vault and i'm trying to authenticate using TLS.
How do I go about it?

Comment: the API is pretty straight forward about this https://www.vaultproject.io/api/auth/cert/index.html

Comment: Yeah, i got it. I was actually trying to do it using the CLI, but got it!

Answer (score 2):

We  can use either self signed certificate in hashicorp vault itself using PKI secrets engine or you can use a third party certificate also both works.If you are taking the self signed option which is recommended, you need to enable the PKI secret engine first.

Steps:

1.Create a dedicated role to use for PKI Secret engine.

2.Generate Intermediate&Root certificate.

3.Make sure that you assign the ttl which is the expiry time of the certificate , if you have not then it will take the default ttl which is 12h.

4.You have to set the config urls to identify the ca ceritificates.

5.You need to add a section following tls_disable=0 with ca and root certificate path.

Here is the reference link for the commands.

https://medium.com/@java.developer.raman/installing-hashicorp-vault-and-root-certification-authority-to-generate-certificates-b0520087137

https://medium.com/@java.developer.raman/enable-vault-authentication-via-cert-rather-than-tokens-c041d3031108